# What is the replacement of /etc/hostconfig

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

I'm working on NetBoot related stuffs, it requires a config in `/etc/hostconfig`. But this file is no longer exist in my system.

After a quick Google I found that as of OS X Yosemite, `/etc/hostconfig` is no longer installed as part of the OS.

So what is the replacement of it?

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: The tag `osx-ei-capitan` was newly created in this question. It is incorrect so I deleted it. The correct tag would be, if any, `osx-el-capitan` (notice the lowercase letter L instead of a lowercase letter "i"). See the correctly spelled tag in Apple.StackExchange.Com: [el-capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/el-capitan).

Comment: Apple warned us for years that "This file is going away." - etc/hostconfig is gone from Yosemite. #RIPhostconfig

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, I think it's `scutil`.  For instance, I am setting the `HOSTNAME` with

```
sudo scutil --set HostName my-host-name
```

(Also, the sudo is optional – if you leave it away, you may just get a TouchID prompt, for instance.)